# Data is saving successfully in mongoDB but response is jumping to error field using promises

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

```js
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

require('../DB/conn');
const User = require("../model/userSchema");

router.post('/register', (req, res) =>{
    const {name, email, phone, work, password, cpassword} = req.body;

    if(!name || !email || !phone || !work || !password || !cpassword){
        return res.status(422).json({error : "please fill all required field"});
    }

    User.findOne({email:email})
    .then((userExist) =>{
        if(userExist){
            return res.status(422).json({error : "Email already exist"});
        }

        const user = new User({name, email, phone, work, password, cpassword});

        user.save().then(() =>{
            res.status(201).json({message : 'Data saved successfully'});
            console.log(`Data saved successfully`);
        }).catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).json({error : 'registeration failed'});
            console.log(`registeration failed`);
        })
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```